# C++ Calculating ticket prices based on age, then summing them

Tags: c++

I have to make a very simple program that asks the user how many tickets he/she wants to buy. It then asks for an age for each of the tickets. Then it should be able to calculate the total cost of the tickets using these prices:

- If the owner is over 15 years old then the ticket costs 80.
- Otherwise, if the owner is at least 8 years old then he pays 30.
- Children younger than 8 years can get a ticket for free.

My question is how do I get it to calculate the total price of the tickets?

this is how far I have come:

I'm using a while loop to get the user to enter multiple ages 
and an if statement to assign prices to the different ages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age, tickets, persons, price, total_price;
    persons = 1, total_price = 0;

    cout << "How many tickets do you want? ";
    cin >> tickets;
    cout << "Number of tickets: " << tickets << endl;
    while (tickets >= persons) {
        cout << "Enter age for person " << persons << ": ";
        cin >> age;

        {
            if (age > 15)
                price = 80;
            else if (age < 8)
                price = 0;
            else
                price = 30;
        }

        price + total_price;

        persons++;
    }
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `price + total_price;` should be     `total_price+=price;`

Comment: It was that simple huh. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Raul and your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current statement `price + total_price;` you accomplish nothing. Change that to `total_price += price;` and you will start to add `price` to `total_price` every iteration of your `while`-loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age, tickets, persons, price, total_price;
    persons = 1, total_price = 0;

    cout << "How many tickets do you want? ";
    cin >> tickets;
    cout << "Number of tickets: " << tickets << endl;
    while (tickets >= persons) {
        cout << "Enter age for person " << persons << ": ";
        cin >> age;

        {
            if (age > 15)
                price = 80;
            else if (age < 8)
                price = 0;
            else
                price = 30;
        }

        total_price += price;

        persons++;
    }
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price;

    return 0;
}
```